# Unable to parse JSON object in JS from PHP json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, json, parameters

I have an array in PHP, which I pack to JSON object with _json_encode(..)_ . Then I send it to JS function as parameter. When I want to parse the object in Javascript with *eval(..)* nothing happens (there is an error behind the curtains I guess). What could be wrong?
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testFun(inArr) {
      var obj=eval('('+inArr+')');
      alert(obj.m); //alert(obj) also doesnt work
    }
</script>  


//PHP
$spola_array = array('m' => 1, 'z' => 2);
$json_obj=json_encode($spola_array);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">testFun('.$json_obj.');</script>';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's already parsed since you're outputting it as an object literal and not a string.  That will look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">testFun({m: 1, z: 2});</script>
```

So in your function, it's just:

```
alert(inArr.m) //1
```

You would only need to parse it if it were a string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">testFun('{m: 1, z: 2}');</script>
```

Comment: BIG thanks for this one. Couldn't figure it out in past hours.

Comment: No problem.  Sometimes it can help to debug things like this with console.log by the way.  It typically provides a better formatted output than alerts.

Comment: Where is this console.log? Edit: do you mean Firebug? I've never used it before and maybe I should start :)

Comment: It's just a function the dev tools of Chrome and IE expose, and a function exposed by Firebug in Firefox.  You just use it like `console.log("test!");` or `console.log(someVar);`  It's not meant to be used in production code.  It's just a slightly more useful way of doing `alert(someVar)`.  It typically includes a little bit of information about the type of variable, and in the case of object literals, it will show that they are objects and show which keys are defined.

Comment: Thanks, great piece of advice.